# Parsing html content with python and modifying it

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and i don't know many things.I want to parse an html page,modify it and show it in my own page.I try use beautifulsoup in order to parse html but some errors are generated.I searched on the web but i don't know any specific way to do this.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Give the code you have and the errors you get, and somebody may be able to help you. Not everybody here is a mindreader.

Comment: this is the problem.i have tried different codes i have found on the net but doesn't satissfy me.If anyone can provide me with a useful link or code i would be pleased.

Comment: Dude, either you provide reasonable information and error messages or just don't ask here. BeautifulSoup is the perfect choice. Unless you provide information there is nothing we can do

Comment: i don't have a specific code.i ask if someone can give me any link or code on how retrieving content from html page,modifying it and extract the content on my page.that's all.:)

Answer (score 1):

Read the BeautifulSoup documentation - and come back if you have real issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can see an example [here](http://www.brianjones.ca/archives/2008/01/27/extracting-content-from-websites-using-beautifulsoup/)

Besides two more discussion in this site:[How to tell BeautifulSoup to extract the content of a specific tag as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922969/how-to-tell-beautifulsoup-to-extract-the-content-of-a-specific-tag-as-text-with)  and [Using Beautiful Soup Python module to replace tags with plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061718/using-beautiful-soup-python-module-to-replace-tags-with-plain-text)

But I think it may be a better idea to write your own code and post your specific question here. Or at least you should use search engine first.

Good luck.